# How to pass object to function in method

Tags: php

I am tying to do following

```
class abc{

   public function abc(){

      someFunction(){
          now here I can not call bcg function like due to scope of function 
          function bcg(){
               $this->bcg();
         }

      }

   }

   public function bcg(){
     ...
   }
}
```

Now my question is how to pass object of current class to function which in method of class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass through your current object into an anonymous function / closure by passing it into it as an argument:

```
// In an object method
$yourFunc = function ($object){
   $object->bcg();
}
$yourFunc($this);
```

If your function is defined outside of your class, you may also use this as a solution:

```
function myFunction($object) {
    $object->bcg();
}

class Foo {
    public function bgc() {
        // ...
    }
    public function doSomething() {
        myFunction($this);
    }
}
```

Note that your `bcg` function will be accessed from the public scope, so `protected` or `private` functions will not work.

Comment: **Fatal error: Cannot use $this as lexical variable**. (I'd remove the first one), the second one works.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a function inside a class method.

This should work:

```
class abc {

    public function abc() {
        $this->bcg(); // You can all bcg() here now
    }
    public function bcg() {

    }
}
```

Comment: @kelunik Thanks for the info. I learnt something new today :)